# Getting Stale Element Reference Exception while accessing the element from a list

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Below is the code which I am trying to get to work.

```
//Method to fetch all links from the sitemap container

public void GetAllLinks() {

        WebElement pointer = LinksContainer;
        String url = "";
        List <WebElement> allURLs = pointer.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println("Total links on the page: "+ allURLs.size());

        for (int i=0; i<allURLs.size(); i++) {
            
            WebElement link = allURLs.get(i);
            url = link.getAttribute("href");
            
            OpenAllLinks(url);
        }
    }
    
    
    //Method to hit all the fetched URLs
    
    public void OpenAllLinks(String linkURL) {
        
        driver.get(linkURL);
}
```

I am fetching all the anchor elements from a sitemap page and then putting all those elements into a list. Then, I am getting the URLs from all those elements using the `getAttribute(href)`. The code is working fine till here.

However, after that I am taking these URLs as arguments and passing into the method `OpenAllLinks()` to open all these URLs one by one using `driver.get()`. The code works till the first link but as soon as the first page is loaded, it gives me the stale element exception.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the error you're getting.

Comment: Hi @DmitriyPopov. Thanks for your comment. I was getting the stale element exception as I was navigating away from the page from where I extracted all the links. I was able to achieve the desired result by using the solution posted by Prophet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you are leaving the page where all these links are appearing all the web elements in `allURLs` list becoming stale elements.
What you can do is first to extract and save in a list all the links, not the web elements, and after that iterate with loop opening all these links.
Like this:

```
public void GetAllLinks() {

    WebElement pointer = LinksContainer;
    String url = "";
    List <WebElement> allURLs = pointer.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    System.out.println("Total links on the page: "+ allURLs.size());
    List<String>links = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=0; i<allURLs.size(); i++) {
            
        WebElement link = allURLs.get(i);
        url = link.getAttribute("href");
        links.add(url);    
    }

    for (int i=0; i<links.size(); i++) {
            
        OpenLink(links.get(i));
    }
}
    
    
//Method to open the fetched URLs
    
public void OpenLink(String linkURL) {        
    driver.get(linkURL);
}
```